# How can i imlplement Encryption with single key and decryption with multiple keys in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, typescript, encryption

I want to encrypt data with a single key and decrypt it with multiple keys. I used the crypto library for this. Code used for it mention below that encrypt with single key but decrypt also with the same key but I required to decrypt with multiple keys. Pls, Give me any suggestions to achieve it. I am working in node js with typescript.
code is as below-->

```
  const crypto = require("crypto");
  const algorithm = "aes-256-ctr";
  const secretKey = "vOVH6sdmpNWjRRIqCc7rdxs01lwHzfr3";

  encrypt = (text: string) => {

  let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
  let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, secretKey, iv);
  let encrypted: any = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(text), 
  cipher.final()]);
  let hash: any = {
  iv: iv.toString("hex"),
  content: encrypted.toString("hex"),
   };
    return hash;
    };

    decrypt = (hash: any) => {
    if (hash.iv) {
    const decipher =     
    crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm,
    secretKey,Buffer.from(hash?.iv, 
    "hex"));

    const decrpyted = Buffer.concat([
    decipher.update(Buffer.from(hash.content, 
    "hex")),decipher.final(),]);
     return decrpyted.toString();
     }
     };
```

Comment: What algorithm are you using? What algorithm supports asymmetric encryption with multiple public keys mapped to a single private key or vice versa?

Comment: i used algorithm "aes-256-ctr"

Comment: That's a symmetric algorithm.

Comment: what can I do for solving this problem? pls guide further.

Comment: What's the point of all this? I understand using a keypair (i.e. one key to encrypt and one key to decrypt), but what's the point of having multiple keys to decrypt?

Comment: Actually, i was required to encrypt my data with a key that is a combination of (public key+private key ).but  I want to decrypt it with 1,2,3 multiple private keys.
 for example secret key = public key+user login password
and now I required decrypted it with the user login password

Comment: This sounds like the type of homemade cryptography that is almost guaranteed to be vulnerable to attack. Anyway, still don't see the point, and cannot help you further. You could try your luck on https://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: You could try using a separate key derivation function (KDF), which produces the same key for different inputs, something like hash collisions in a weak hash function. Give different users different colliding hashes, so they all get the same real key after processing. Add the KDF to your code to process what the user enters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting question. Following on from my comment, here is a possible example.

Your key would be `SHA256("13378ADKKQTY")` or some such. The hashed string can be longer if you want. Note that the digits are in order, as are the letters, and all letters are capitals.

You then disguise the string to be hashed by shuffling it and adding in lowercase letters and special characters: "D3gj/K3YTop71!mAms8KbQs". Each recipient gets a different disguised string. When your code receives the disguised string it strips out the special characters and lowercase letters. Then it sorts the digits and uppercase letters into order, which gives the correct string to hash. Hashing that string gives the real key.

Basically you disguise the key differently for each person, and make sure that the disguises are removable.